# How to resolve error says "No matching function call for XXX"?

Tags: c++, templates

Why did I get "No matching function for call to 'getVector'" error about the assignment line statement?

```
template <typename T>
vector<T> getVector(int);

int main() {
    auto myVector = getVector(5);
    ...
}

template <typename T>
vector<T> getVector(int size) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the vector you want to return?

Answer (score 3):

Look at what your compiler says! It's trying to help you.

> main.cpp:7:21: error: no matching function for call to 'getVector'

And then:

> main.cpp:4:16: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument `'T' std::vector<T> getVector(int);`

The error is very clear: the compiler sees your `getVector` function, but you never mentioned a "concrete" type to substitute for `T`: the compiler has no idea what you want the vector to hold, so it simply ignores that function template.

What kind of values do you want to store in the vector? Integers for example? Then:

```
auto myVector = getVector<int>(5);
                          ^ give a type here
```

Comment: Thank you! That explains my confusion. But I have another question, what if I don't know the "concrete" type that should substitute for T? Like, I want to get numbers from a file, but I don't know what type those numbers are.

Comment: Templates are a *compile time* construct: if you don't know `T` at compile time, then you cannot instantiate the template. But you could use a type that can hold anything: for example look into `boost::any`. This way you can have a `std::vector<boost::any>` which can effectively hold `int`s, `float`s, you name it. The drawback being that you have to check the type of the elements in the vector before you manipulate them.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `getVector()` as a function template that takes a template argument `T`. That template argument needs to be provided somehow. You can't call the function without `T` either being deduced or explicitly provided.

For example, if the vector you are returning holds integers, you can provide `int` for `T` like this:

```
auto myVector = getVector<int>(5);
```